# How Can I Format Strings With T-Sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, function, format

I want use 1000 separator(,) for numeric values.

how can i format strings with T-Sql Functions?

Comment: SQL Server is about **storing** data - the **formatting** for display should be done in your front-end application (web app or whatever). SQL Server / T-SQL doesn't have any extensive formatting capabilities.

Comment: Whilst it is absolutely the case that one should do conversion formatting as late as possible - as close to the "user" as possible - it is also the case that there may well be a good reason to need to do so in a query in this case - therefore the comment as written (i.e. without asking for clarification/justification) is not really a positive contribution and certainly NOT a great comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select convert(varchar(10), cast(1234.333 as money), 1)
```